# how to get pci_dev from file object in a driver's ioctl()?

Tags: linux, driver, device

I'm working on a linux driver for a **PCIE** hardware. The kernel is `v4.13`.
For each device object, there is a bunch of data stored with `pci_set_drvdata(struct pci_dev *pdev, void *data)`.

In `IOCtl()` service routine, how can I get the data back using `struct file * pFile` ?

```
long IOCtlService(struct file * pFile, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have more then one device you are likely using an IDR to allocate and track minor dev node IDs. The call to `idr_alloc` accepts a pointer to store with the ID for future use.

In your ioctl handler you can then lookup the pointer from the idr using `idr_find`. For example:

**Allocate an IDR and store `info` with it**

Global defines

```
DEFINE_MUTEX(minor_lock);
DEFINE_IDR(mydev_idr);
```

In your PCI probe handler

```
struct my_dev * info;

info = kzalloc(sizeof(struct mydev_info), GFP_KERNEL);
if (!info)
  return -ENOMEM;

mutex_lock(&minor_lock);
info->minor = idr_alloc(&mydev_idr, info, 0, MYDEV_MAX_DEVICES, GFP_KERNEL);
if (info->minor < 0)
{
  mutex_unlock(&minor_lock);
  goto out_unreg;
}
mutex_unlock(&minor_lock);

pci_set_drvdata(dev, info);
```

**Lookup the stored pointer from the IDR**

```
unsigned minor = iminor(flip->f_inode);
struct my_dev * dev = (struct my_dev *)idr_find(&mydev_idr, minor);
if (!dev)
  return -EINVAL;
```

**Make sure to free your IDRs on device removal**

```
mutex_lock(&minor_lock);
idr_remove(&mydev_idr, info->minor);
mutex_unlock(&minor_lock);
```

Comment: When you look up the stored pointer from the IDR, I think you need to look for `mydev_idr` not `my_idr`, no?

Comment: @Sam you're correct, this is an error in the above example. I have corrected this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `ioctl()` driver will take command & work on those commands as

```
 ioctl(fd, cmd , INPARAM or OUTPARAM);
```

how can I get the data back using struct file * pFile ? what operation you want to perform ? you can use commands which are available in `ioctl.h`  for this.
for e.g `IOR` (If the command needs to read some thing from the kernel
space)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what I need is the data I attached to the device object when it's created, not the arguments the application input in ioctl().  Here are the steps. I create a device in deviceadd() and attach some device instance related data, or DEVICE_EXTENSION, to it using pci_set_drvdata() or dev_set_drvdata(). When my driver gets a ioctl call, I need to attain the device extension data related to the device instance. However there is only pfile, a file * pointer, in ioctl() service routine. To call pci_get_drvdata() or dev_get_drvdata(), I need a pci_dev * or a device *.

Answer (score 0):

`struct file` also have `private_data`, so you can store `pci_dev` there, just like what `struct miscdev` does:

```c
static int misc_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
    ......
    struct miscdevice *c;

    ......

    /*
     * Place the miscdevice in the file's
     * private_data so it can be used by the
     * file operations, including f_op->open below
     */
    file->private_data = c;
}
```